# How to delete oldest file from SD card with SdFat

Tags: arduino, sd-card, arduino-c++

I'm trying to delete the oldest file from an sd card with SdFat with no success

I've found that function on Arduino forums
[Here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=530065.0)

```cpp
void deleteOldestFile(){
  SdFile dirFile;
  SdFile file;
  SdFile oldestFile;

  dir_t dir;
  uint32_t oldestModified = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  uint32_t lastModified;

  if (!dirFile.open("/", O_READ)) {
    sd.errorHalt("open root failed");
  }

  while (file.openNext(&dirFile, O_WRITE)) {
    // Skip directories and hidden files.
    if (!file.isSubDir() && !file.isHidden()) {
      file.dirEntry(&dir);
      lastModified = (uint16_t (dir.lastWriteDate) << 16 | dir.lastWriteTime);
      if (lastModified < oldestModified ) {
        oldestModified = lastModified;
        oldestFile = file;
      }
    }
    file.close();
  }
  if(!oldestFile.remove()) Serial.println("failed");
  dirFile.close();
}
```

but I'm getting a "failed" message when this function run
any idea why and how to fix this problem?

EDIT:
I can use remove like that:

```cpp
  char delChar[13] = {0};
...
  Serial.print("oldest: ");
  oldestFile.printName();
  oldestFile.getName(delChar,13);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("delchar: ");
  Serial.println(delChar);
  if(!sd.remove(delChar)) Serial.println("fail");
  dirFile.close();
```

but the `file.remove()` still not works

Comment: A first step to debug the problem might be to print the file name of `oldestFile` before calling `oldestFile.remove()` and maybe print the file name and lastModified whenever you assign something to `oldestModified` and `oldestFile`.

Comment: The file is correct, but I discovered that the```FatFile::remove``` not working at all, no matter what.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add all information there instead of writing comments. If you modified your code to print debug output, update the code in the question and show the resulting output. If you suspect that `FatFile::remove` does not work, try a minimal program that attempts to remove a single hard-coded file name. The code should print the file name and the result of `remove()`. Please show this output. Maybe you can enable debug output in the library to see the file name and line number where the error was detected.

Comment: I haven't used this particular SD file library, but I suspect some of the code:

Comment: I have a really stupid question: Does the SD card you're using have a Write Protect switch, and is that Write Protect switch off? I've been burned by that problem once or twice.

Answer (score 1):

I see one bug in the code, that will cause problems finding the oldest file. It's not the main cause of the file.remove() problem, but it will cause trouble once you find and fix the file.remove() problem.

lastModified = (uint16_t (dir.lastWriteDate) << 16 | dir.lastWriteTime);

That uint16_t should be uint32_t instead. That error will cause the file's lastWriteDate to be treated as zero, because shifting an unsigned 16 bit number 16 bits to the left causes the result to be zero.

Here's a Sketch to illustrate the problem:

```
/*
 * Simple Arduino Uno Sketch to show a bug and its corrected code.
 */

uint32_t oldestModified = 0xFFFFFFFF; // Tip: use 0xFFFFFFFFul to be unambiguous


uint16_t lastWriteDate = 5; // an arbitrary date
uint16_t lastWriteTime = 3; // an arbitrary time

void setup() {
  uint32_t badLastModified;
  uint32_t lastModified;

  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(4000); // to give the user a chance to open the serial monitor.

  Serial.print("oldestModified = 0x");
  Serial.println(oldestModified, HEX);

  badLastModified = (uint16_t (lastWriteDate) << 16 | lastWriteTime); // original
  lastModified =    (uint32_t (lastWriteDate) << 16 | lastWriteTime); // corrected

  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("badLastModified = 0x");
  Serial.println(badLastModified, HEX);

  Serial.print("lastModified = 0x");
  Serial.println(lastModified, HEX);

}

void loop() {
}
```

Running this Sketch on an Arduino Uno produced this output:

```
oldestModified = 0xFFFFFFFF

badLastModified = 0x3
lastModified = 0x50003
```